# Flutter Cursor Position on Text Field

Tags: flutter

I want to append text after the cursor position. For example: when the user moved the cursor of the text field middle. I want to get the cursor location on the text and I'll add text after the cursor location.

I tried with Text Edit Controller but I can't reach the cursor location with this. How can detect the cursor location on the text field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I fixed my problem with this;

```
// Get cursor current position
                    var cursorPos =
                        _textEditController.selection.base.offset;

                    // Right text of cursor position
                    String suffixText =
                        _textEditController.text.substring(cursorPos);

                    // Add new text on cursor position
                    String specialChars = ' text_1 ';
                    int length = specialChars.length;
                    
                    // Get the left text of cursor
                    String prefixText =
                        _textEditController.text.substring(0, cursorPos);

                    _textEditController.text =
                        prefixText + specialChars + suffixText;
                    
                    // Cursor move to end of added text
                    _textEditController.selection = TextSelection(
                      baseOffset: cursorPos + length,
                      extentOffset: cursorPos + length,
                    );
```

Answer (score 2):

### An alternative to [@secret's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65654957/2837443)

```dart
final selection = textController.selection;
final offset = selection.baseOffset;
textController.value = textController.value.replaced(TextRange.collapsed(offset), someText);
```

Comment: better solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
int position =  controller.selection.base.offset;
```

simply get the cursor position and split it by firstpart and secondpart add the text what you want to insert.   like

> controller.text=firstpart+"someText"+lastpart;