# how can i add emoji in flutter text field

Tags: flutter

i have the following `column`

```
 late  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
    Column(
    children:[
     GestureDetector(
         onTap: (){
          // 1- here How can i copy the emoji 
          // 2- add it to controller (locate it to the current location where text field cursor located )
         },
        child: Text('')
       ),
        TextField(
        controller: controller ,
        )
     ]
    )
```

1- here How can i copy the emoji

2- add it to controller (fitting it to the current location where text field cursor located )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to insert text in middle of text field text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057840/flutter-how-to-insert-text-in-middle-of-text-field-text)

Answer (score 0):

[Emoji Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter)

You can use this library.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            String text = controller.text + '';
            setState(() {
              controller.value = TextEditingValue(
                  text: text,
                  selection: TextSelection(
                      baseOffset: text.length, extentOffset: text.length));
            });
          },
          child: Text('')),
```

Comment: it always add emoji at end length

Comment: to add text at current index of cursor you can use the code provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65654957